# Python 3.6 Error when installing pip install gearman

Tags: python, python-3.6, gearman

I have been trying to install gearman on python 3.6 but I'm getting this error:

```
$ pip install gearman
Collecting gearman
  Using cached gearman-2.0.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-xmf1cqe7/gearman/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        from gearman import __version__ as version
      File "/tmp/pip-build-xmf1cqe7/gearman/gearman/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
        from gearman.admin_client import GearmanAdminClient
      File "/tmp/pip-build-xmf1cqe7/gearman/gearman/admin_client.py", line 4, in <module>
        from gearman import util
      File "/tmp/pip-build-xmf1cqe7/gearman/gearman/util.py", line 62
        except select_lib.error, exc:
                               ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-xmf1cqe7/gearman/
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

pip -V -> pip 9.0.1 from [my_project_folder]/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)

python --version -> Python 3.6.2

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gearman package does not support Python 3. Only python 2.4-2.7 are supported according to their [setup.py](https://github.com/YelpArchive/python-gearman/blob/master/setup.py). There is an open [pull request](https://github.com/YelpArchive/python-gearman/pull/82) to add python 3 support but it has been untouched for a year.  I believe that Yelp! may have stopped supporting this library.

Answer (score 0):

You use python3 and in python3 
Use as instead:[the raise syntax no longer accepts comma-separated arguments.](http://docs.pythonsprints.com/python3_porting/py-porting.html)

The `gearman` is not the Python 3 version, you can check the link https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gearman